# Union null values to a array of struct in Big Query

Tags: arrays, struct, google-bigquery

I have the following table in Big Query which has an array of struct type. I have to perform a union operation with a simple table and want to add null values in place of the nested columns.

Actual nested table example -
[image]

Simple table (which needs to be union-ed)

| acc | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acc_6 | 11/29/2022 | 2 |
| acc_8 | 11/30/2022 | 3 |

I tried the following query but it gives an error of incompatible types on the nested columns

```
select * from actual_table 
union all
select acc, date, count,
array_agg(struct(cast(null as string) as device_id, cast(null as date) as to_date, cast(null as string) as from_date) as d
from simple_table
```

The resultant table should look like this -
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `d` has a type of *array of struct<string, string, string>*, you need to write a `null` struct like below.

```sql
SELECT * FROM actual_table
 UNION ALL
SELECT *, [STRUCT(CAST(null AS STRING), CAST(null AS STRING), CAST(null AS STRING))] FROM simple_table;
```

- `[]` is for array literal. see [Using array literals](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#using_array_literals)
- field names in `null` *struct* are optional cause they are already declared in `actual_table` before *union all*.
- you can use `STRING(null)` instead of `CAST(null AS STRING)` which is a little bit concise.

**Query results**

[image]